# datastore.first() , .last() , .map() etc methods are missing / unresolved reference error in all projects in Android Studio , idk why they disapeared

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-datastore

I don't know why this is happening , yesterday it was working well but this time when i opened the project again , **it is missing these methods** :- `datastore.data.first()`,`datastore.data.last()` , and other similar methods are also missing it seems like they all belongs to kotlinx.coroutines and are extension functions .
**Ide shows unresolved reference** but my all dependencies are correct , what can be the error here ?
I have tried invalidate cache & Restart , rebuild , clean project .
please anyone help me here !

Here is [dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBNVE.png) used in project ,
here is a [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihOqC.png) for error reference

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: sure , will not do again

Comment: show me your gradle plugin and project level gradle file

Comment: Thanks for your reply , actually it was solved last night .